# Передача данных между наследниками синглтона и состояниями

Tags: c++, singleton, шаблон-одиночка

**Доброго времени суток!**

Сначала немного объяснения архитектуры, для самого вопроса

В данный момент пишу консольный чат с использованием `curses`. Основа клиентской части похожа на игровой движок - есть сцены, которые являются *singleton*, и есть менеджер сцен, который их изменяет. Но есть проблема.

Вот *базовый класс сцены* (опущу лишнее) (как я понял, это является паттерном состояний (`state`), поэтому называются не сцены, а состояния):

```
class State {
public:
    virtual void Init() {}

    //...

    template <class T>
    static T* Instance() {
        static T m_state;
        return &m_state;
    }
protected:
    State() {}
    State(State const&) = delete;
    State& operator= (State const&) = delete;
};
```

Вот *класс менеджера сцен* (приведу лишь нужную часть) (да, он тоже singleton):

```
class StateManager {
public:
    //...

    template <class T>
    void ChangeState() {
        if (!m_states.empty()) {
            m_states.back()->Destroy();
            m_states.pop_back();
        }
        m_states.push_back(State::Instance<T>());
        m_states.back()->Init();
    }

    template <class T>
    void PushState() {
        if (!m_states.empty()) {
            m_states.back()->Pause();
        }
        m_states.push_back(State::Instance<T>());
        m_states.back()->Init();
    }

    static StateManager& getInstance() {
        static StateManager manager;
        return manager;
    }

private:
    std::vector<State*> m_states;

    StateManager() {}
    StateManager(StateManager const&) = delete;
    StateManager& operator= (StateManager const&) = delete;
};
```

**Чего у меня не хватает тут:**

Между сценами мне нужно передавать разные данные, причем у некоторых сцен не надо их передавать. То есть моя идея была в добавлении шаблона для функции `Init()` и для `PushState() / ChangeState()` для неопределенного числа параметров

```
template <class T, class Arg...>
void PushState(const Arg&... args) {
    if (!m_states.empty()) {
        m_states.back()->Pause();
    }
    m_states.push_back(State::Instance<T>());
    m_states.back()->Init(args...);
}
```

Проблема сама в том, что если для отдельных сцен делать свой `Init(Type param)`, то в менеджере будет вызываться функция именно базовой сцены, а не наследника.

**Суть вопроса:**

Как можно реализовать подобную передачу параметров?

Если есть идеи лучше, то буду рад их почитать.

**Спасибо за внимание!**

Comment: Вообще-то синглтон класс не может иметь наследников и должен быть объявлен как `final`

Comment: @AGS17 А можно немного по-подробнее? Что значит не может иметь наследников? Если это правила этого паттерна, то я могу немного схитрить и изменить их в угоду себе. Мне нужны тут синглтоны, чтобы быть уверенным в том, что сцены будут в одном экземпляре и я не смогу их создать без менеджера.
В данном случае у  меня не совсем наследник синглтона, скорее наследник его функций, каждая сцена сама определена как синглтон.

Comment: это правила паттерна. _сцены будут в одном экземпляре_ - создавайте их в менеджере и там же ими управляйте.

Comment: @AGS17 То есть отказаться от одиночек в сценах впринципе? Но как это решает мою проблему?

Comment: @MechanicL Это не то, чтобы решает вашу проблему, это просто вопрос правильной реализации паттерна. Ну и да, синглтон не нужен, тем, что сцена одна, должен управлять менеджер сцен. (Единственность сцены — не неотъемлемое свойство самой сцены, а свойство вашей бизнес-логики. Значит, в бизнес-логике и надо заботиться о единственности ваших сцен.)

Comment: А почему бы вам общие для всех сцен данные не просто положить в отдельный класс (который собственно и инкапсулирует состояние), и не передавать его? Ну да, некоторые сцены получат лишние данные, это же не такая большая проблема?

Comment: @AGS17 а что мешает иметь наследника? Ну будет наследник или базовый существовать...

Comment: @pavel то, что это тогда не будет являться **синглтоном**.